# Visiting a website behind CloudFlare with PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, cloudflare

I'm trying to write a webbrowser with PyQT5, using QWebView. When I try to access a website without cloudflare everything works like a charm. But when I tried to access a website behind Cloudflare ( When I'm Under Attack Mode activated), my browser keep trying to connect that website and looks like refreshes page after a while(cause RayID value changes like every 4-5 secs). Any suggestions?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage, QWebView

class BrowserSettings(QWebPage):
    '''
        Browser settings.
    '''
        def userAgentForUrl(self, url):
        '''
            Returns User-Agent value.
        '''
        return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1295.0 Safari/537.15"

class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.setPage(BrowserSettings())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
browser = Browser()
browser.show()
browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://websiteaftercloudflare.com/"))
app.exec()
```

Comment: Fairly  sure it is down to your headers provided, can you share the link?

Comment: I have not change the default headers. But when I compare the headers with my original browser's headers, I see that only DNT header don't sended.